# Greatest function in Teradata is throwing error with more than two arguments

Tags: teradata

When I am executing the below code `select greatest(13,6,20,30)` in Teradata , it is throwing the below error:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Function 'greatest' called with an invalid number or type of parameters
SELECT Command Failed.
```

Although it is working with two arguments. As per documentation of version 16.* this function can accept till 10 arguments. I am working with Teradata version 16.2. Is there anything wrong with the SQL statement?

Comment: I'm assuming that isn't the literal command you are trying?  Make sure you aren't mixing data types in your argument list.

Comment: Most likely someone installed a custom UDF in default SYSLIB database (not recommended) with the conflicting function name GREATEST. Try explicitly qualifying the function name as `TD_SYSFNLIB.GREATEST` to be sure you are picking up the Teradata-supplied one.

Comment: Thank you Fred for the suggestion. TD_SYSFNLIB.GREATEST worked for me.